# How to get all the attachment IDs of a work item in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, power-automate, azure-devops-rest-api

I am working on building a power automate flow to retrieve the attachments of a work item and send it for approval in the email. I am making use of "Send Http Request to Azure DevOps" task.

The below API requires attachment ID to passed.

**GET [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/attachments/{id}?api-version=7.0](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/wit/attachments/%7Bid%7D?api-version=7.0)**

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/attachments/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)

How can I retrieve all the attachment IDs of a work item (user story) ? Please help me with the APIs for the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP#workitemexpand) with $expand parameter. You`ll receive we following information:

[image]